# Filter by Product Properties with Store API

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

For the store API endpoint `/store-api/product` is it possible to filter on the properties of a product? Not the defaults such as whether it's active or stock levels, but the properties we've defined on the product, for example `colour` or `farbe`? For the search endpoint it supports passing in a list of `properties` ID's which this one does not.

None of the below queries work, and return the various errors below or `Call to a member function buildAccessor() on null`.

```
{
    "limit": 40,
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "contains",
            "field": "Farbe",
            "value": "red"
        }
    ]
}

"Field \"Farbe\" in entity \"product\" was not found."

{
    "limit": 40,
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "contains",
            "field": "properties.Farbe",
            "value": "red"
        }
    ]
}

"Field \"Farbe\" in entity \"property_group_option\" was not found."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine filters for the name of the property value and their respective group in a multi filter. The following example will only give you products that have the "shoe-color" property with the value "coral".

```json
{
  "limit": 1,
  "includes": {
    "product": ["id", "productNumber", "properties"],
    "property_group_option": ["name", "group"],
    "property_group": ["name"]
  },
  "associations": {
    "properties": {
      "associations": {
        "group": []
      }
    }
  },
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "multi", 
      "operator": "and",
      "queries": [
        {
          "type": "equals",
          "field": "properties.group.name",
          "value": "shoe-color"
        },
        {
          "type": "equals",
          "field": "properties.name",
          "value": "coral"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Example response:

```json
{
    "entity": "product",
    "total": 1,
    "aggregations": [],
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 1,
    "elements": [
        {
            "productNumber": "6bbfe1f608504c9b9a7bf92d6a071734",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "coral",
                    "group": {
                        "name": "shoe-color",
                        "apiAlias": "property_group"
                    },
                    "apiAlias": "property_group_option"
                },
                {
                    "name": "cotton",
                    "group": {
                        "name": "textile",
                        "apiAlias": "property_group"
                    },
                    "apiAlias": "property_group_option"
                }
            ],
            "id": "062ba988aa1840fa84371c9c43b2f838",
            "apiAlias": "product"
        }
    ],
    "states": [],
    "apiAlias": "dal_entity_search_result"
}
```

Comment: Do you also have an example of filtering based on whether a product is visible in listings only vs search? Not seeing that information surfaced in any endpoints.